# React Router does not replace the previous page content

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to navigate to a page on button click using the following code:

```
    this.props.history.pushState(null, "page2");
```

It changes the URL in address bar and shows me the content of targetURL on the current page itself, rather than hiding the previous page content.

Below is my router code:

```
const routes = (
<Router history={createBrowserHistory(historyOptions)}>
    <Route path='/' component={BaseLayout}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
);
```

I am using react router version: 1.0.0 . How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score -2):

Try removing the slash.
`<Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>`